# Is there a way to define a port range in Stunnel?

Tags: linux, networking, ssl, stunnel

I have multiple clients on the same box that will connect to the same domain. Each client needs to go through a different port. I can just define the entries multiple times, but is there an easier way to list out an accepted consecutive range of ports?

```
# stunnel.conf

[client-1]
client = yes
accept = 127.0.0.1:5098
connect = target-domain.com:443

[client-2]
client = yes
accept = 127.0.0.1:5099
connect = target-domain.com:443

[client-3]
client = yes
accept = 127.0.0.1:5100
connect = target-domain.com:443

[client-4]
client = yes
accept = 127.0.0.1:5101
connect = target-domain.com:443

[client-5]
client = yes
accept = 127.0.0.1:5102
connect = target-domain.com:443
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can have ranges in `stunnel` configuration.

`stunnel` documentation at https://www.stunnel.org/static/stunnel.html says:

> An address parameter of an option may be either:
>
> A port number.
>
> A colon-separated pair of IP address (either IPv4, IPv6, or domain name) and port number.
>
> A Unix socket path (Unix only).

(note: **a** port number)

and:

> accept = [HOST:]PORT
>
> accept connections on specified address

Possible alternate solutions I can think of (not an exhaustive list):

- auto generate the `stunnel` configuration from some other source with any kind of template system (that will allow a simple loop command to generate each statement from a port range),
- define a single port and use `iptables` to forward each client port to the only one defined in `stunnel`; or the `redir` command (https://linux.die.net/man/1/redir)
- use other software, like `HAProxy` as its `bind` option specifically allows port ranges: `bind [<address>]:<port_range> [, ...] [param*]` and: `<port_range> is either a unique TCP port, or a port range for which the proxy will accept connections for the IP address specified above.`

Comment: Do you know if forwarding the port using `iptables` would cause any issues with multiple concurrent HTTPS/TCP sessions?

Comment: @ajoseps It should not change anything. See this question for some help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/104824/port-forward-to-a-port-on-the-same-machine

Comment: I guess either way I would need to autogenerate `iptable` commands or autogenerate the stunnel.conf. It's just a matter of what conf file I choose to autogenerate.